# an iframe html element does not show the website i want it to. Instead, it just says "site refuses to connect"

Tags: html

I have an html page with an iframe element.

I tried

```
src="https://www.google.com"
    height="360"
    width="640"
    >
</iframe>`
```

but in the element it just said "www.google.com refused to connect."

How to fix this without php? Thanks.

Comment: the only solution is to ask google to authorize this display and reprogram their management for this automation.
Good luck..